# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl when try to update cocoapods with Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, libcurl

I want to add Google Analytics to my ios app, 
So when I try `pod install` I got

```
[!] Error installing Google
[!] /usr/local/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/3_/j0hsqdp94lq_g08t50s3p5_r0000gn/T/d20151102-49906-p891cj/file.zip https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/02468137448ba914-Google-1.0.7.zip --create-dirs

curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: it means your curl (or actually libcurl, that curl uses) was built without HTTPS support. You need to either install another libcurl or rebuild it from source, to add that capability.